# How can I join a base URL to partial URLs from a list using For Loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, url

I have a list called URL_list. I looks like this:
[item-1.html',
'item-2.html',
'item-3.html']

I want use a for loop to join the base URL "http://www.examplesite.com/" to each partial URL in my list.

Here's what I tried, but it's not working:

```
full_URL = [ ]

for base in URL_list:

URL += "http://www.examplesite.com/"

print(full_URL)
```

What should I do to attach the beginning of the URL, "http://www.examplesite.com/", with each item in my list to get a list of the full URLs?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725189/how-can-i-prepend-each-value-of-a-list-with-either-a-loop-or-a-function/73725263#73725263

Answer (score 0):

You can either concatenate the string or use f-string for each of the values in the list together with the base URL, you can accomplish it using List Comprehension:

```py
>>> parts = ['item-1.html', 'item-2.html', 'item-3.html']
>>> [f"http://www.examplesite.com/{v}" for v in parts]

['http://www.examplesite.com/item-1.html', 'http://www.examplesite.com/item-2.html', 'http://www.examplesite.com/item-3.html']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the above one:

```
page = ['item-1.html', 'item-2.html', 'item-3.html']
fullUrl=[]
for base in range(len(page)):
    fullUrl.append("http://www.examplesite.com/"+page[base])
    print(fullUrl[base])

#To print all links as list
print(fullUrl)
```